# Validate field not in model by Django rest

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a model:

```
class EventTracker(models.Model):
"""
Track events of user's behaviors
"""
class Meta:
    verbose_name = "EventTracker"
    verbose_name_plural = "EventTrackers"
    unique_together = ("application", "label")

application = models.ForeignKey(Application, related_name='events')
label = models.CharField(max_length=50)
count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
value = models.IntegerField(null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return "[{}] {}".format(self.application, self.label)
```

This is my serializer for this model:

```
class EventTrackerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
subscriber_id = serializers.IntegerField(min_value=1)

class Meta:
    model = EventTracker
    fields = ('id', 'application', 'label', 'count', 'value', 'subscriber_id')
    write_only_fields = ('subscriber_id', )
    read_only_fields = ('count',)
```

subscriber_id is a field that doesn't belong to this model. But request data must have subscriber_id to do a thing. So I want to validate it in serializer. I don't know how to validate it. I tried like above, it threw error:

```
This may be because you have a writable field on the serializer class that is not a valid argument to.....
```

So what can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should probably be more explicit about what you want to do. We don't know what that field is for nor if it's readable nether what/how you want to validate it, so I'd do some guesswork.

Assuming it's write only:

```
subscriber_id = serializers.IntegerField(min_value=1, write_only=True)
```

Note that the `write_only_fields` has been removed for some time.
Next, you'll have to write manually the serializer's create/update. Example for the create:

```
class EventTrackerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
    def create(self, validated_data):
        subscriber_id = validated_data.pop('subscriber_id')
        instance = EventTracker.objects.create(**validated_data)
        return instance
```